# Unit testing for Spring Cloud Gateway Custom Filter Factory

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have implemented the custom filter factories for Cloud Gateway. However, I couldn't figure out the way to write unit testcases. 
While exploring the default Filter Factories test cases, I found that majority of factories test classes extends [BaseWebClientTests](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/master/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/test/BaseWebClientTests.java) and other classes which are in test package.

My question is that shall I copy paste those intermediate test classes to my local test package? What's community recommendation here?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. Spring has mock classes for server web exchange, request and response

Comment: Thanks let me try.

Comment: Also, found this problem, do you have any solutions? @RahulSharma

Comment: Not yet. I shall explore Mock class as suggested in previous comment.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my result, for your information

```java
class CustomGatewayFilterFactoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private CustomGatewayFilterFactory factory;

    private ServerWebExchange exchange;
    private GatewayFilterChain filterChain = mock(GatewayFilterChain.class);
    private ArgumentCaptor<ServerWebExchange> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ServerWebExchange.class);

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        when(filterChain.filter(captor.capture())).thenReturn(Mono.empty());
    }

    @Test
    void customTest() {
        MockServerHttpRequest request = MockServerHttpRequest.get(DUMMY_URL).build();
        exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(request);
        GatewayFilter filter = factory.apply(YOUR_FACTORY_CONFIG);
        filter.filter(exchange, filterChain);
        // filter.filter(exchange, filterChain).block(); if you have any reactive methods

        ServerHttpRequest actualRequest = captor.getValue().getRequest();

        // Now you can assert anything in the actualRequest
        assertEquals(request, actualRequest);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to capture filter Config in this test? It seems it's impossible. I mean the config is not initialized and I have to do it manually.

Comment: Little late, but do you know how to mock a response? This works for every line before the `Mono.fromRunnable` but it doesn't get the lines inside of it.

Comment: @icsllaf you can use [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito) to mock any response :)